# HashMap Homework, issue with templates

Tags: java

I'm trying to write the get method for a hashmap of custom objects.

```
public V get(K key){
    int hashval = (int)(Math.abs(key.hashCode()) % this.capacity);
    for(Data<K, V> d : hashmap.get(hashval) ){
        System.out.println("hashval: " + hashval);
        System.out.println("d.getKey:" + d.getKey() + " class: " + d.getKey().getClass());
        System.out.println("key:" + key + " class: " + key.getClass());

        if (d.getKey() == key){
            System.out.println("d.getValue: " + d.getValue());
            return d.getValue();
        }
    }
```

I would expect that if d.getKey() and key print the same value and the same class type, then the if statement should come out true, and print the value which should be being returned. However, this is the result I get:

```
hashval: 5  
d.getKey:12345 class: class java.lang.Integer  
key:12345 class: class java.lang.Integer
```

The line inside the if statement does not show up. What silly problem am I overlooking? I think it might have something to do with templates, since key is the generic type K?

Comment: The correct term is Generics in Java.

Comment: Also, this is a question of the `==` operator applied to reference types.

Comment: It's not necessarily only applicable to `Integer`, but you'll get the idea.

Comment: That clears it up, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
d.getKey().intValue() == key.intValue()
```

you can use == only for primitive data type, For Objects you can  use equals method to compare an attribute value as

```
   d.getKey().equals(key)
```

Comment: What if the key isn't an Integer?

Comment: AS per OP's question the key is of type java.lang.Integer

Comment: "you can use == only for primitive data type":  this is very untrue ... but you -do- have to know what you're doing.  Sometimes you actually do want to test for identity and sometimes you actually do want to test for equality.

Comment: In this test case the key was an Integer but the OP is trying to make a generic HashMap which would work for any key, right?

Answer (score 2):

`if (d.getKey() == key)` is not correct. you need to use  `if (d.getKey().equals(key))`